# Same actionbar items on every Activity not rewriting code

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I am using ActionBarSherlock to implement an UI using this powerful AB as a Menu. This is the menu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/capturador"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_capturador"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/capturador"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/preferencias"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_prefs"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/preferencias"/>   

</menu>
```

As you can see it has two items (*capturador* and *preferencias*)

So, what I wanna do -if it's possible- is to re-use code. It's not a big deal because I just have two more activities apart from Main activity but what if I had five? Should I overwrite in each activity the *onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)* and *onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)* methods?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.capturador) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Capturador.class));
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.preferencias) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Ajustes.class));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry if this question was already answered but I don't really know which words I must use to try to find it (besides, English is not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make an `BaseActivity` in which you implement this code, and then let all your `Activities` that you want to have this 2 options menu, extend your `BaseActivity`.

Comment: That was a really helpful tip but what if each Activity extends by definition a different kind of Activity?

For example, for the Settings activity I extend PreferenceActivity but for the ListView activity I extend ListActivity.

Thank you very much!

Comment: yes, in this scenario this won't apply, since we can't extend multiple classes